# Reformatting HTML in Adobe Brackets

Tags: formatting, adobe, code-formatting, adobe-brackets

Is there a way to have Adobe Brackets automatically reformat an HTML file for me? I don't mean change the code, I mean indentation.

For example, I might be given a file that has code like this:

```
<div>
  <strong>James Doe.</strong>
  </div>
```

It is easier to read like this:

```
<div>
  <strong>James Doe.</strong>
</div>
```

Is there something that can do this automatically in Brackets? If not, another application? Rather than me going through and reformatting the lines manually.

Answer (score 2):

The "Beautify" extension is probably what you're after.
Just open the Extension Manager and search for "Beautify".